# How do I pick the correct solution for the QNM?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

I am following The [paper](https://www.edleaver.com/Misc/EdLeaver/Publications/AnalyticRepresentationForQuasinormalModesOfKerrBlackHoles.pdf) by Leaver in order to calculate the QNM of a Schwartzschild black hole, however I am a bit confused: how do I pick the correct solution for $\omega$? Solving the equation with continued fraction:

$$0=\beta_0-\dfrac{\alpha_0\gamma_1}{\beta_1-}\dfrac{\alpha_1\gamma_2}{\beta_2-}....$$
gives a plethora of solutions, I thought that the actual ones had a real part positive, but there is more than one.

Which is the correct one? Did I misunderstand the solution process?

Comment: Permalink: https://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1985.0119

Comment: For those of us not in the field, please don't use acronyms in subject lines.   We have to click in in order to judge if we can contribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of them are valid quasi-normal modes. The quasi-normal modes of a black hole for a three index family labelled by $l$, $m$, and $n$. In setting up the equation for the Schwarzschild QNMs you only chose the $l$ and $m$. $n$ does not feature in the equation. The label $n$ simply labels all the solutions to the equation (ordered by increasing imaginary part).

Typically, you are most interested in the fundamental $n=0$ mode for a given $l$ and $m$. This is the slowest decay QNM and therefore usually the most prominent.

Note that not all solutions are equally easy to find from the continued fraction equation. You can change which solutions are easiest to find by performing so called inversions of the continued fraction (essentially choosing which term in the recurrence relation you start from). In Leaver's words:

> Although each inversion of (14) has the same solutions as (13),  the topology of the function  on  the  right-hand  side  of  the  equation  changes  markedly  with  the  number  ofinversionsn.   The $n$th quasi-normal  mode  is  usually  found  to  be  numerically  the  most stable root of the $n$th inversion.

When you move to Kerr things become even worse since you can no longer fix $l$ a priori in Leaver's method and the couple set of continued fractions that you are solving has all QNMs with a fixed $m$ but varying $l$ and $m$ as its solutions.